# How to add an ImageButton to label using c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, imagebutton

I am tring to add an ImageButton to a label using C# but I don't success.... Can someone help me?

Thanks

This is what I did- (Delete is the name of the label)

```
var img = new ImageButton();
img.ID = "delete" + i;
img.ImageUrl = "images/1395958363_meanicons_57.png";
img.OnClientClick = "Delete_Click";
img.Width = 48;
img.Height = 38;
Delete.Page.Form.Controls.Add(img);
```

Comment: Why do you want to add it to a label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Delete is the name of the Label (I suggest renaming it DeleteLbl or something similar) then you're going go to the label, getting a reference to the page, then the form on the page, then adding the ImageButton to that. That's convoluted. Instead, I think you want to add it directly to the Label's controls.

```
Delete.Controls.Add(img);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be adding an ImageButton control to a Label control.  That doesn't seem like a semantic use of the Label control (which is supposed to be used to display text).

However, you generally want to add sub-controls to the `.Controls` collection of whatever control you're trying to add it into, not the Page's or Form's `.Controls` collection.  Like this:

```
Delete.Controls.Add(img);
```

---

Instead of a Label, you should probably use [a PlaceHolder control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.placeholder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="myControlHolster" runat="server" />
```

And then add your ImageButton to that:

```
myControlHolster.Controls.Add(img);
```

Answer (score 0):

ou can use the following code, where 2.jpg is your button image:

```
<asp:button id="myButton" style="background-image:url('2.jpg'); background-color:red; cursor:hand;" Runat="server" Height="25px" BorderStyText="ButtonText" Width="200px" />
```